# Go language: Wait() does not return when sending data to spawned process

Tags: go

I need to send several MB to a spawned Go process. I followed the directions at https://gobyexample.com/spawning-processes, but my data is too large to send that way. I thought I could chunk the data. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
doit := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd)    // cmd reads stdin
doit_stdin,_  := doit.StdinPipe()
doit_stdout,_ := doit.StdoutPipe()

doit.Start()

go func() {
  w := bufio.NewWriter(doit_stdin)
  for i := 0; i < nchunks; i++ {
    w.Write(input_data[chunk_begin[i]:chunk_begin[i+1]]) 
    w.Flush()
  }
  doit_stdin.Close()
}()

rc,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(doit_stdout)
doit.Wait()
```

Where `input_data` is `[]byte` and `chunk_begin` is an array of break points computed elsewhere. Everything works just fine. `cmd` gets all the data sent to it, detects EOF, sends results back and exits. `ReadAll` gets all the info sent back from cmd. But `do it.Wait()` blocks. I cannot understand why `doit.Wait` is blocking.

Or if there is some other standard way of transferring larger amounts of data, that would be fine too. I do need to control the break points because the data has internal structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain `Wait` is blocking? Have you confirmed the call to `stdin.Close()` completed? Why are you writing a single byte at a time, and why are you using a buffered writer if you Flush after every byte?

Comment: Hi Jim. At your suggestion, I did put in some more error checks, and things do seem to be OK. The data is not going byte at a time, the chunk_begin array is typically spaced so that data goes in units of around 50k bytes.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed `chunk_begin` was being indexed, not the bytes themselves. If all your data is sent, and the stdin pipe is getting closed, then the command being executed by bash simply isn't exiting and you need to debug that. Does `cmd` _require_ being run in a shell? Can you provide input as a single `io.Reader` to the process's stdin and see if that changes anything without the pipe?

Comment: Hi Jim I did look closer and the problem is that I was being impatient! Usually Go is fast, but my 28 MB file was taking too long. I just needed to wait a little and not be so impatient. Hopefully others will find this post helpful. Thank you JimB, your comments helped a lot. Ian

Comment: Mark this as answered, @JimB

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the input program.

cmd.Wait waits for the writer to finish.
The call `doit.StdinPipe().Close()`, does not affect the writer, although, I have to admit I find this surprising.

I concocted an example to demonstrate this;

```golang
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "io/ioutil"
  "math"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  doit := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "md5sum")
  doitStdin,_  := doit.StdinPipe()
  doitStdout,_ := doit.StdoutPipe()
  doit.Start()
  inputData := generateCrapForever()
  k32 := 33
  nchunks := len(inputData) / k32
  chunkBegin := make([]int, nchunks)
  var i = 0
  for i<nchunks {
    chunkBegin[i] = i*k32
    i++
  }

  go func() {
    w := bufio.NewWriter(doitStdin)
    for i := 0; i < nchunks-1; i++ {
      last := int(math.Max(float64(chunkBegin[i+1]), float64(len(inputData))))
      w.Write(inputData[chunkBegin[i]:last])
      w.Flush()
    }
    doitStdin.Close()
  }()

  rc,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(doitStdout)
  doit.Wait()
  println(string(rc))
}

func generateCrapForever() []byte {
  out, _ := exec.Command("dd", "if=/dev/urandom", "bs=10" ).Output()
  return out
}
```

If you substitute generateCrapForever() with generateCrap(), then the code works. But if the input pipe never exits, and keeps writing, then cmd.Wait will never stop, because it is waiting for the input-pipe to finish.

```golang
  func generateCrap() []byte {
    out, _ := exec.Command("dd", "if=/dev/urandom", "bs=10", "count=33").Output()
    return out
  }
```

Actually, in this example, the blocking code is `generateCrapforever()` and not `cmd.Wait`. Perhaps something similar is happening in your code?